# Create index on existing table Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing

Is it safe to create an index on an existing table in oracle?

Like this:

```
CREATE INDEX table_sample_ix03
      ON table_sample
(
  col4,
  col22
)
TABLESPACE data
STORAGE
(
  INITIAL        10M    NEXT          2M
  MINEXTENTS      1     MAXEXTENTS  100
  PCTINCREASE     0
)
;
```

Answer (score 15):

The ONLINE clause is recommended when you create the index while DML queries are being run on the table. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm

Example:

```
CREATE  INDEX "MYINDEX" ON "MYTABLE" ("MYCOLUMN")  ONLINE;
```

Comment: From your link: _"Specify ONLINE to indicate that Data Manipulation Language (DML)  operations on the table will be allowed during creation of the index."_ `Create` is an Data Definition Language (DDL) operation and there are Restrictions on Online Index Building.

Comment: that's without the quote and empty space....! CREATE INDEX ix_customernumber ON lp_temp_deactMobiel(customernumber) ONLINE;

Comment: It would be always best to create Index on existing table with 'PARALLEL' clause set to some value to create index faster on huge data.
Later you can alter the Index and set 'NO PARALLEL'.

In our legacy project we follow this approach.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. But if possible, you should do it while no one is updating the table, because they would suffer performance-wise (it is still safe to do it anyway, there will be no data corruption).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Why wouldn't it be?

I can only think of possible performance issues just after issuing the command. If the table is very large, the indexing can take some time but other than that, it should be fine.